# IIS Rewrite to remove certain querystring parameters and redirect to the original requested host

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I need to write a redirect to strip off parameters when a certain one exists, but I would like the redirect to be the same as the incoming url, just without the parameters. This is what I had and it doesn't work. I thought if I put the request URI in there without appending the querystring, then it would work but it results in a loop. Has anyone done this before?

```
<rule name="Remove parameters" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
<conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
  <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="page=([0-9]+)" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" />
```

Comment: Title says remove certain parameters while body of question says remove all parameters. Lucky us that we have answers for both below :)

Answer (score 9):

The problem with jallen's answer is that the **whole query string** will be removed, which may not be ideal if you want to maintain certain parts of it. An alternative would be as follows:

```
<rule name="Remove paging parameters" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)?$" />
    <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(.*)(page=.+)(.*)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}{C:3}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

- C:1 = Everything before the matching `page` parameter
- C:2 = Is the
  match itself, and what we want to exclude
- C:3 = Everything after the
  matching `page` parameter

Hence, we use the redirect `{C:1}{C:3}` to exclude *only* the page query string.

Answer (score 4):

Got it with the following:

```
<rule name="Remove paging parameters" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)?$" />
<conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
  <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="page=([0-9]+)" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
```